# How to run multiple commands using subprocess.check_call at one go

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run multiple commands at one go using subprocess.ckeck_call in my python script but not working.

```
>>> subprocess.check_call("testdriver ssh scaler-1"; "mkdir deb" shell=True)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    subprocess.check_call("testdriver ssh scaler-1"; "mkdir deb" shell=True)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Will appreciate if anyone can provide the syntax

Comment: python doesn't use the `;` char (at least not as you showed).

Comment: ok so what should i use to run multiple commands

Answer (score 2):

Surely you meant

```
subprocess.check_call("testdriver ssh scaler-1; mkdir deb", shell=True)
```

Comment: Yes but it fails    

    >>> subprocess.check_call("testdriver ssh scaler-1; mkdir deb" shell=True)
      File "<stdin>", line 1
        subprocess.check_call("testdriver ssh scaler-1; mkdir deb" shell=True)
                                                                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Surely you meant `subprocess.check_call("testdriver ssh scaler-1; mkdir deb", shell=True)`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, i missed the , before shell=True